# Fastest ADO to copy paste tables from sql-server to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ado

I'm moving tables of data from sql-server into Excel.
I do not need to move through the record set only to grab the data and paste it into a worksheet.

Am I using the correct arguments for the recordset's `Open` method?

```
Dim recSet As ADODB.Recordset
Set recSet = New ADODB.Recordset
aConnection.Open
recSet.Open stringSQL, aConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText 
wb.Sheets(sName).Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset recSet
recSet.Close
If Not (recSet Is Nothing) Then
    If (recSet.State And 1) = 1 Then recSet.Close
    Set recSet.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    Set recSet = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675544(v=vs.85).aspx), yes your arguments are correct. If your `stringSQL` is not that complicated and your `RecordSet` is not that large, this should be instant.

Comment: @L42 never more than 5000 rows by 10 columns?

Comment: Ah mine is around 45,000  and took 140~150 sec approximately in my machine. Btw, the location of the source takes into account as well. My source is located in a server common drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the approach that I've use to extract the data from MSSQLServer, maybe it will be useful for you:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Connection As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim QT As Excel.QueryTable
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim SQL As String
    Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ConnectionString = ""
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable"
    Connection.Open ConnectionString
    rs.Open SQL, Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

    Set QT = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(rs, ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1))
    QT.Refresh:    rs.Close:    QT.Delete:    Connection.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great, because QueryTables keeps the column name, unlike Range.CopyFromRecordset Method.

The following link provide a way to copy existing Excel data to recordset. I know it may not related to the first question, but combine with your answer fulfil the missing part and enable alot of ways to workwith recordset in excel, thank you.

https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/vba-trick-of-the-week-range-to-recordset-without-making-connection/