# VBA to Populate data from SQL query into Excel table

Tags: sql, excel, vba, populate

I am extracting sales data from SQL table and populate it into "Table1" in "Sheet1"
per below code below:

```
Sub SalesPerCountry()
    Dim NewRow As ListRow
    Set Table = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

' Set Connection and run
    Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Connection.Open "Provider=###;Password=###;User ID=### ;Data Source=###
    Set SQL1 = Connection.Execute("Select Country, Sum(Sales) as Sales From [Market_Sales]   
               Group by Country")

'  Delete data from table
        If Not Table.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then Table.DataBodyRange.Delete

'  Populate data
    r = 0
    While Not SQL1.EOF
        r = r + 1
        Set NewRow = Table.ListRows.Add(r)
        NewRow.Range(1) = SQL1("Country").Value
        NewRow.Range(2) = SQL1("Sales").Value
        SQL1.MoveNext
    Wend

End Sub
```

I need to make the code more efficient as table is very big now and macro takes minutes to run.

I want to be able to push all data at once into the excel table, something like below:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Value = SQL1
```

but this doesn't run

any idea how to push the SQL1 object data into the table?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `CopyFromRecordset` to populate the entire result set.

Comment: Pls try `CopyFromRecordset`.  _Microsoft documentation:_

> [Range.CopyFromRecordset method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159876/fastest-ado-to-copy-paste-tables-from-sql-server-to-excel/28160883#28160883